# Error with reading JSON file lines in Django app

Tags: python, json, django

I have this code but I have some lines in my JSON file with empty lines. And I get this error.
This is a Custom Command and I get this error. I want to create a list of jobs in The database of my Django app, I am using a For loop. Thank a lot for your help

```
 raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from jobs.models import Job
import json

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Set up the database'

    def handle(self, *args: str, **options: str):
        with open('static/joblist03112020.json', 'r') as handle:
            for line in handle.readlines():
                print(line)
                line = json.loads(line)

                existing_job = Job.objects.filter(

                    job_title = line['job_title'],
                    company = line['company'],
                    company_url = line['company_url'],
                    description = line['description'],
                    salary = line['salary'],
                    city = line['city'],
                    district = line['district'],
                    url = line['url'],
                    job_type = line['job_type'],

                )
                if existing_job.exists() is False:
                    Job.objects.create(

                        job_title = line['job_title'],
                        company = line['company'],
                        company_url = line['company_url'],
                        description = line['description'],
                        salary = line['salary'],
                        city = line['city'],
                        district = line['district'],
                        url = line['url'],
                        job_type = line['job_type'],

                    )

                    Job.save()
                    self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCES('added jobs!add'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to load the entire JSON file instead of loading line-by-line. Not every line in a JSON file is guaranteed to be parseable in itself as a valid JSON object.

Here is the spirit of what I think you want to do:

```py
with open('static/joblist03112020.json') as f:
    job_list = json.load(f)
```

Note that opening with `'r'` for read is the default, so I removed it.

Now you can iterate through each job in the list, and apply the filter. If your JSON object keys match the columns of your model, you may be able to simplify that code as well:

```py
for job in job_list:
    existing_job = Job.objects.filter(**job)
    if not existing_job.exists():
        Job.objects.create(**job)
```

Note that you will not need to call `.save()` since `create` includes saving. Also, the `.save()` method is only defined on an instance of the class anyway.

Comment: `

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Set up the database'

    def handle(self, *args: str, **options: str):
        with open('static/joblist03112020.json') as f:
            job_list = json.load(f)
            for job in job_list:
                existing_job = Job.objects.filter(
`    like this?

Comment: what yo mean match my model? same fields? and same order of fields?

Comment: If the fields are the same, you can use the dictionary unpacking operation (`**`) to pass the arguments to the `filter` and `create` commands.

Answer (score 0):

someone out of this platform helps me with my problem. this is what I did. and solve the problem. I needed to work with big JSON

```
 def handle(self, *args: str, **options: str):
            with open('static/data.json', 'r') as handle:
                big_json = json.loads(handle.read())
                for item in big_json:
                    existing_job = Job.objects.filter(
```